# Admin check if an admin user has administrator privileges - programmatically

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, administration

I am trying to find a provision for checking out the privileges of current logged in user, I am able to get the data of current logged admin from session, but struggling to get the privileges it has, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps?

`Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$id = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
$roleData = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($roleData);
```